# How to add jQuery Chosen plugin to Magento 2 checkout fields

Tags: magento2, checkout, jquery, knockoutjs

How to add [jQuery Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin to the checkout fields in Magento 2 so that customer can search in country list for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One way** to approach this is by creating Knockout binding. Info on that can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110233/knockout-with-chosen-doesnt-set-the-initial-selected-options) In this approach all data changes are done by the Knockout and you need to hook into it to call `$(element).trigger('chosen:updated');` to update Chosen UI.

I also needed to do some CSS styling as some times Chosen dropdown would have `width:0`

**Another approach** that was suited for my situation as I needed to update country and region dropdowns in the checkout was to use Chosen `change()` function to update the UI, as data was still updated by Knockout.

So I created a function that checked if the loader is visible and once it was removed initialized Chosen with a `change()` function to update the UI. Add this script to the head of `checkout_index_index.xml`

```
require([
    "jquery",
    "chosen.jquery"
], function ($) {
    $(function () {
        var initChosen = function(){

            if($('#checkout-loader').length > 0) {
                setTimeout(initChosen, 200);
            } else {
                $('select').chosen().change(function(){
                    $('[name="region_id"]').trigger("chosen:updated");
                });
            }

        };

        initChosen();

    });
});
```

Also [this link](http://realize.be/mobile-support-chosen) was useful to make Chosen work on mobile